# Numpy histogram on multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

given an np.array of shape `(n_days, n_lat, n_lon)`, I'd like to compute a histogram with fixed bins for each lat-lon cell (ie the distribution of daily values).

A simple solution to the problem is to loop over the cells and invoke `np.histogram` for each cell::

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 10)
B = np.rand(n_days, n_lat, n_lon)
H = np.zeros((n_bins, n_lat, n_lon), dtype=np.int32)
for lat in range(n_lat):
    for lon in range(n_lon):
        H[:, lat, lon] = np.histogram(A[:, lat, lon], bins=bins)[0]
# note: code not tested
```

but this is quite slow. Is there a more efficient solution that does not involve a loop?

I looked into `np.searchsorted` to get the bin indices for each value in `B` and then use fancy indexing to update `H`::

```
bin_indices = bins.searchsorted(B)
H[bin_indices.ravel(), idx[0], idx[1]] += 1  # where idx is a index grid given by np.indices
# note: code not tested
```

but this does not work because the in-place add operator (+=) doesn't seem to support multiple updates of the same cell.

thx, 
 Peter

Comment: seems like https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2821 addressed the fancy indexing and inplace issue. The reason why numpy doesn't allow multiple updates is that ``a[idx] += 1`` would not be the same as ``a[idx] = a[idx] + 1`` .

Comment: Use [`np.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) with the `weights` keyword argument.

Comment: @Jaime how would I use the ``weights``? I don't want to do a 2d histogram.

Comment: There's also a `np.histogramdd` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.apply_along_axis()` to eliminate the loop.

```py
import numpy as np

hist, bin_edges = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.histogram(x, bins=bins), 0, B)
```

Comment: @PeterPrettenhofer just fixed a typo.  lambda had letters transposed.  Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?:

```
import numpy as np
n_days=31
n_lat=10
n_lon=10
n_bins=10
bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, n_bins)
B = np.random.rand(n_days, n_lat, n_lon)


# flatten to 1D
C=np.reshape(B,n_days*n_lat*n_lon)
# use digitize to get the index of the bin to which the numbers belong
D=np.digitize(C,bins)-1
# reshape the results back to the original shape
result=np.reshape(D,(n_days, n_lat, n_lon))
```

Comment: this gives me basically the same as ``bins.searchsorted(B)``, an array of shape ``(n_days, n_lat, n_lon)`` but the tricky part is how to transform it into ``(n_bins, n_lat, n_lon)``.