# apply numpy.histogram to multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, histogram

I want to apply `numpy.histogram()` to a multi-dimensional array along an axis.

Say, for example I have a 2D array and I want to apply `histogram()` along `axis=1`.

#### Code:

```
import numpy

array = numpy.array([[0.6, 0.7, -0.3, 1.0, -0.8], [0.2, -1.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.8], 
                    [0.25, 0.3, -0.1, -0.8, 1.0]])
bins = [-1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]
hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(array, bins)
print(hist)
```

#### Output:

```
[3 3 3 4 2]
```

#### Expected Output:

```
[[1 1 0 2 1],
 [1 1 1 2 0],
 [1 1 2 0 1]]
```

How can I get my expected output?

I tried to use the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851471/numpy-histogram-on-multi-dimensional-array), but it doesn't get me to the expected output.

Comment: you can use `apply_along_axis` as suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871667/8366805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n-d cases, you can do this with `np.histogram2d` just by making a dummy x-axis (`i`):

```
def vec_hist(a, bins):
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(np.product(a.shape[:-1]), a.shape[-1]))
    return np.histogram2d(i, a.flatten(), (a.shape[0], bins)).reshape(a.shape[:-1], -1)
```

Output

```
vec_hist(array, bins)
Out[453]: 
(array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  1.]]),
 array([ 0.        ,  0.66666667,  1.33333333,  2.        ]),
 array([-1.       , -0.5      ,  0.       ,  0.5      ,  0.9999999,  1.       ]))
```

For histograms over arbitrary axis, you'll probably need to create `i` using `np.meshgrid` and `np.ravel_multi_axis` and then use that to reshape the resulting histogram.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I appreciate. can you give me an example in case of having n-dimensional array? your solution works for 2d case.

Comment: Expanded it to n-d, but it only works if the histogram is over the last axis.  And implementation over arbitrary axes will need a lot more work.

Comment: can you give me an example? In my case, I need to apply histogram over the last axis.

Comment: Fixed some errors, should hopefully work now for multidimensional.

Comment: Not working anymore. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy code changed and the answer proposed by Daniel F is not working anymore.
Here is a simplified version for 2D arrays:

```
def vec_hist(a, bins):
    i = np.tile(np.arange(a.shape[0]), (a.shape[1], 1)).T.flatten()
    H, _, _ = np.histogram2d(i, a.flatten(), (a.shape[0], bins))
    return H
```

So basically first we build a list of coordinates "i" that is simply the index of the data along the last axis.
Then we flatten it, along with the data array "a" before sending it to np.histogram2d. The bin argument of histogram2d are the bin the dummy and the actually desired dimension.

Code:

```
array = np.array([[0.6, 0.7, -0.3, 1.0, -0.8], 
                  [0.2, -1.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.8], 
                  [0.25, 0.3, -0.1, -0.8, 1.0]])
bins = [-1.0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]
vec_hist(array, bins)
```

Output

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 2., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 2., 0.],
       [1., 1., 2., 0., 1.]])
```